# getJSON no output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, weather-api

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is not working?

```
<div class="clouds">

</div>

<div class="station">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("http://api.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat=53.36652&lng=-2.29855&username=jolones&callback=?",
function(data){

          var clouds = data.weatherObservation.clouds;
          var station = data.weatherObservation.stationName;

      jQuery.(".clouds").html(clouds);
      jQuery.(".station").html(station);

      });
```

Much appreciation

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` to debug your response.

Comment: Running issues like this through jslint will isolate your errors many times, just saying. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery . (".clouds").html(clouds);
jQuery . (".station").html(station);
```

Do you mean to have those dots there?  Should be

```
jQuery(".clouds").html(clouds);
jQuery(".station").html(station);
```

Comment: I hate myself, but I'm a massive fan of you. Thanks ever so much.

Comment: No problem!  Though it looks like what @Mike said is also an issue.

Comment: I don't see the "mike" issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/YxcWy/1/ - scattered clouds in manchester eh

Comment: Comes up as 'broken clouds' in Manchester for me.  Didn't know there was such a thing as broken clouds.

Answer (score 0):

Browser security policy prevents you from making json ( xmlhttpReqeusts ) to another domain. You should lookup how JSONP works though, this may be useful if geonames.org provides a jsonp method ( jsonp would allow you to do this and call another domain ).

Another option is to create a local php script that calls the api remotely. PHP is not prohibited to call a remote api, so you could use php to retrieve the json results and then use javascript to retrieve the results from your local ( on same domain ) php program.

Comment: Look up and see it ends with `&callback=?` and most likely is a JSONP call.

Comment: jQuery 1.5 started treating any getJSON request with ?callback= in the URL as a JSONP request by default, so the request will still work http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp

Comment: @steveukx good to know, i'll have to make sure i'm running latest